# Are there any difference between `<h1> ... <h6>` tags for SEO?

Tags: html, seo, tags, heading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Heading tags like <h1> and <h2> make a big differences during SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4524/does-heading-tags-like-h1-and-h2-make-a-big-differences-during-seo)

Are there any difference between `<h1> ... <h6>` tags for SEO ?

For example, `<h1> Most Important </h1>
<h6> Less Important </h6>`

Comment: Use whichever one provides the best semantic description of its contents. Optimize elsewhere.

Comment: Again i can't understand , why this question get negative vote :)

Comment: It got a negative vote becuase it's not a question related to programming or development

Comment: So, where should is ask this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

absolutely yes.

the best practice is to structure your content like a normal office document, by using paragraphs with titles.

important to know is, that you should use the tags for it's desire. so use a table only for a real table, a list for a list, and so on. with the mentioned tags you should structure titles and subtitles of your content.

a common practice is, to use only one h1 tag each site. its the main title of it and it should differ from the `<title>` tag itself.